# Ubuntu Software Center won't install packages correctly

Tags: software-center

Is there a better way to install packages than the Ubuntu Software Center as mine can be very glitchy and not always work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I have found to install applications is to search for them in the terminal with sudo apt search (application), and then sudo apt install (application).